# Object is returning method as property when I console.log

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods

I have a constructor to create products and a method to check if there's stock. The problem is that when I try to console.log the product is being displayed with the method.

```
class Product{
    constructor(id, name, price, stock){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    checkstock = () => this.stock > 0 ? console.log("Available stock") : console.log("No stock");
}
const product1 = new Product(001, "Keyboard", "$19.95", 3);
product1.checkstock();
console.log(product1)
```

The result was this:

```
Product { checkstock: [λ: checkstock],
  id: 1,
  name: 'Keyboard',
  price: '$19.95',
  stock: 3 }
  ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​product1
```

Comment: How is this a *problem*? A method is just a property whoes value is a function. `console.log` is a debugging tool. Knowing what methods are available on an object when you log it is useful.

Comment: Your code with the arrow function field initialiser is equivalent to writing `this.checkstock = () => { if (this.stock > 0) … };` in the constructor. Don't do that, use method definition syntax

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the 'checkstock' method declaration with an arrow function.

It is preferable to use a more classical syntax.

```js
class Product{
    constructor(id, name, price, stock){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    checkstock() {
        return this.stock > 0 ? console.log("Available stock") : console.log("No stock");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods are usually [functions on the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#inheriting_methods). They are shared among instances.

But your "method" is indeed an instance's [*own* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). It is *not* on the prototype and therefore *not* shared among other instances.

To define methods, use the syntax for [method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```js
class {
  method() {}
}
```